# Radium error - Unknown plugin "flow-comments"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Got the following error when using radium with reactjs. Is anyone got the solution for this issue?

Radium Verion: v0.14.1
React Version: v0.13.3

```
ERROR in ./~/radium/lib/index.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "flow-comments"
    at PluginManager.subnormaliseString (/home/iswan/os-projects/praxis-samples/03-forms/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/plugin-manager.js:147:13)
    at PluginManager.add (/home/iswan/os-projects/praxis-samples/03-forms/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/plugin-manager.js:190:40)
    at File.buildTransformers (/home/iswan/os-projects/praxis-samples/03-forms/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:237:21)
    at new File (/home/iswan/os-projects/praxis-samples/03-forms/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:139:10)
    at Pipeline.transform (/home/iswan/os-projects/praxis-samples/03-forms/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:164:16)
    at transpile (/home/iswan/os-projects/praxis-samples/03-forms/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:12:22)
    at Object.module.exports (/home/iswan/os-projects/praxis-samples/03-forms/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:69:12)
 @ ./~/praxis/src/ui/Input.jsx 19:14-31
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got the same error. Just try to install flow-comments.

```
npm install babel-plugin-flow-comments --save
```